# Create a body for a UDF in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a `function` in my `sql server` database

**What I wrote :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION CommandesAsTable ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS  

DECLARE MyC CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,QTE,PRU FROM Commande
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(50), @QTE INT , @PRU MONEY, @Total MONEY
DECLARE @R AS TABLE (ID VARCHAR(50), QTE INT , PRU MONEY, Total MONEY)

OPEN MyC
FETCH MyC INTO @ID,@QTE,@PRU

WHILE @@fetch_status =0
BEGIN 
SET @total = @QTE*@PRU

INSERT INTO @R VALUES(@id,@QTE,@PRU,@Total)

FETCH MyC INTO @ID,@QTE,@PRU

END 

CLOSE myc
DEALLOCATE myc       

RETURN @R
```

**But I got this error :**

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CommandesAsTable, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 30]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CommandesAsTable, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 30]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
```

so please how can I use this body inside my function ? and thanks in advance

Comment: Delete almost all of it. You just need `CREATE FUNCTION CommandesAsTable ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT ID,QTE,PRU, QTE * PRU AS Total FROM Commande`. Though as it doesn't take any parameters it should probably be a view

Comment: In SQL Server functions are not intended for DML (data manipulation lang.) like inserting rows.  You'll get an "Invalid use of a side-effecting operator" error

Comment: @SteveC inserting into table variables is allowed in multi statement table valued functions. But completely unnecessary here anyway

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#interoperability) it says: "The following statements are valid in a function ... DECLARE statements defining local data variables and local cursors." So you have to declare the cursor as a cursor variable `@MyC`. Also means you don't need to close it at the end of the function, it will auto-close and deallocate. I would advise to use `FAST_FORWARD` cursor for performance. See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6308/different-ways-to-write-a-cursor-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Do an inline Table Function instead of a multi-statement (with a cursor to be boot), it'll be much faster:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CommandesAsTable()
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
(
SELECT ID,QTE,PRU, Total = QTE * PRU
FROM Commande
)
GO
```

Comment: I know that but I wanna use Cursor I have my reasons, so please do you have any other suggestion and thank you for your time sir